# How to convert datetime from character to normal datetime in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe in r which consists of a column with the following DateTime format with `character` class.

```
dt<-2021-03-01 06:10:31.346
```

I need to convert it into the following format with datetime class.

```
2021-03-01 06:10:31
```

I have tried the following solution but it didn't work.

```
Df$Dt<- as.POSIXct(Df$Dt,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `T` is not needed as it was not present in the original string

```
as.POSIXct(dt, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2021-03-01 06:10:31 CST"
```

If we want to take care of the microseconds

```
as.POSIXct(dt, format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%OS")
```

Also, the `format` is not really needed here as the input is in the accepted format for `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(dt)
#[1] "2021-03-01 06:10:31 CST"
```

#### data

```
dt <- '2021-03-01 06:10:31.346'
```